# Taking logarithm of value using SQLAlchemy - Flask/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to update the `score` attribute of `User` to the logarithm of the existing `score`. However, I do not understand how I can bind a math function to `sqlalchemy.sql.func`.

For example:

```py
import math
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


def mul_2(user):
    return user.score * 2

def _log(user):
    return func.math.log(user.score)


# This works fine
User.query.update({User.score: mul_2(User)})

# This fails
User.query.update({User.score: _log(User)})
```

Comment: The answer to the linked duplicate shows how you can register arbitrary functions with the SQLAlchemy connection to sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's `func` let's you tell SQLAlchemy which database function to use, for example postgresql does support `log()`, so you should be able to call that with `func.log()` but that will be executed with the query by the database.  If you want it executed by Python you need to just call `math.log()`.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-math.html

Comment: Yes, migrating from SQLite to PostgreSQL and applying `func.log()` was the way to go.